# FFmpeg large input frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, real-time

I have a problem that I cannot solve and I would really appriciate your help.

I have large rgb24 frame (1M each) which i would like to stream to ffmpeg and convert them to mpegts h264 stream.

Now, I know which arguments I need to supply to ffmpeg so the conversion will success, but I don't have a clue how can I stream/provide the frames to ffmpeg since they are too large for udp and I can't using files. ( It's a demonstrate of a real time streaming).

Thank for all the helpers It's really important for me!

Answer (score 0):

You may set up an [ffserver](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) (or whatever stream server) and stream [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)/[RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) to it. Not sure why you use this format or why preserving the rawvideo quality is important (since h.264 is quite optimized for high quality video/streams).

Notice: RTMP/RTP is TCP not UDP.

For a better answer, please add some more details to the original question

Good luck! -E